# Web App Architecture PouchDB + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, architecture, pouchdb

For a web application using the PouchDB/CouchDB synchronisation I currently have the following setup:

[image: Recent setup]

At some points, computation on the data is necessary before the results are presented to the user however. I would like to do those computations on the server in the future, as I hope it will generally lead to a more consistent user experience. 
At the moment, I’m using the PouchDB authentication plugin for user authentication (each user has their own database). What I would like to achieve is that for the server side computations the client would make an HTTP request to the server, where the server would fetch the data from the clients private database, does the necessary computations and sends the results back.

[image: Possible future setup]

I’m concerned with two things now: On the one hand, I don’t know how I would check on the server side if the request came from a user authorised to access the database. On the other hand, I’m asking myself if this approach is generally desirable, or if I should generally design the application differently.

Thanks a lot for your advice!

P.S.: I would like to use Vue.js on the client in future versions of the application.

Comment: My approach is to put my application logic in a proxy that sits between PouchDB and CouchDB. This reduces the number of endpoints Pouch needs to care about, and for most things, it looks entirely like CouchDB to PouchDB.  I can just intercept the requests I care about, to do additional transforms as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I'm struggling with the construct of such a proxy that "looks entirely like CouchDB to PouchDB". Does it mean you have a server setup as a proxy that forwards all PouchDB requests to the CouchDB, alters the responses according to the programs logic and then responds to the original request from PouchDB? I'm sorry but I'm still quiet new in the field and don't really know how I would code such a proxy in that case.

Comment: That's essentially right.  Whether that's appropriate for you depends on your app requirements.

Comment: you may want to look at the spiegel design. I use a similar setup where the user writable dbs serve as queues to feed workers running on node that populate shared, metadbs and each users read-side db.